# Oracle query performance with BETWEEN operator

Tags: performance, oracle, query-optimization

I have a table with about 100million rows. Have to use BETWEEN operator. I see that query is running very slow.

I added 2 indexes on trader table one on t.name and second index is t.amount and t.price.

Query is performing very slow. Does indexing on price and amount help when using BETWEEN operator. Also, how can I optimize this?

```
select t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state 
from trader t where exists 
( 
SELECT null 
FROM city_present p,city_state c 
WHERE p.name = 'TEST_TEST'
AND c.city = p.city
AND c.state = p.state
AND t.city = c.city 
AND t.state = c.state 
AND t.price IS NOT NULL 
AND t.price between (25.00000 , 58.000000) 
AND t.amount IS NOT NULL 
AND t.amount BETWEEN (-2500.0000 , 2800.000) 
) 
AND t.name = 'john test' 
AND t.is_valid= 1
```

Comment: Why are you focusing on the BETWEEN? There are lots of other filters as well.

Comment: A correlated subquery on 100 million rows could be a cause.

Comment: Could you provide your query's execution plan?

Comment: t.price IS NOT NULL, t.amount IS NOT NULL are of no use, since you have 
t.price BETWEEN (25.00000 , 58.000000) and t.amount BETWEEN (-2500.0000 , 2800.000)  
correspondingly

Comment: It is pointless to ask a question about query performance without posting the query execution plan.

Comment: Why are there predicates on trader inside the subquery?

Comment: As recommended by other commenters I also recommend posting the query plan. Also, can you tell us how many rows you expect to be returned by this query?

Comment: Hi, I note that you haven't been active for almost 40 minutes and haven't answered a single question yet. Please bear in mind that Stack Overflow moves _fast_. If you want the best answers please always stick around for the first 30 minutes to an hour after asking a question and be prepared to answer questions in the comments immediately.

Comment: Please edit your question and correct the syntax errors.  It's tough to take a question seriously if the query can't even be compiled.  Either that or re-tag it for a database where this query can be compiled successfully.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Selectivity is the key to performance in optimisation - you probably have vastly fewer traders called 'john test', with is_valid = 1, in cities/states where the city_present.name is 'TEST_TEST', than have price between 25 and 58 and amount between -2500 and 2800.

Therefore, I recommend setting up an index on the trader table, on name, city, state and is_valid (in that order), and then try the following query:

```
SELECT t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state 
FROM trader t
JOIN (select distinct p.city, p.state
      from city_present p
      JOIN city_state s
        ON s.city  = p.city AND s.state = p.state 
      WHERE p.name = 'TEST_TEST') c
  ON t.city  = c.city AND t.state = c.state 
WHERE t.price between (25.00000 , 58.000000) 
  AND t.amount BETWEEN (-2500.0000 , 2800.000) 
  AND t.name = 'john test' 
  AND t.is_valid= 1
```

Comment: My reqts. has changed and I have to get the rows from the single trader table which contains about 100Million rows.  Below query is running slow.  I have 2 indexes one on t.name and another on t.city & t.state.  From Execution Plan I see that the t.name is being used but query is doing INDEX ROWID scan for t.amount, t.price, t.city and t.state.

SELECT t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state 
FROM trader t 
WHERE t.name = 'john test'
AND is_valid = 1
AND
((t.amount BETWEEN (-2500.0000 , 2800.000)
AND t.price between (25.00000 , 58.000000)
)
OR 
(t.city='city'
AND t.state='state'
))

Comment: @user12121: How many trader records have the name `'john test'`? How long does your new query take?